# display='page' throws error in JS SDK of Facebook API

Tags: jquery, facebook-graph-api

I am using the following line to invoke the oAuth Dialog of Facebook API:

```
FB.login(checkLoginStatus,{display:'page'}, {scope:'email,user_birthday,user_likes'});
```

this throws an error which says:

```
        "display" must be one of "popup", "dialog", "iframe", "touch", "async", "hidden", or "none" all.js:55
    i all.js:55
    m all.js:96
    i.provide.login all.js:97
    (anonymous function) all.js:80
    (anonymous function) all.js:78
    authUser sample.js:37
    (anonymous function) sample.js:61
    b.event.dispatch jquery.js:3
    v.handle
```

Is the display='page' not applicable for JS SDK or has it been deprecated?

I find this really awkward. In their documentation, it still says:

If you're invoking a Dialog using the JS, iOS or Android SDKs, the display mode will be automatically chosen for you based on the platform and the device being used by the user. However, you can force a particular display mode by setting the display parameter to one of the following values: "page", "popup", "touch", "iframe", "async".

You can find it [HERE](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/)!

Comment: FB.login takes two parameters, you are giving it three ... combine the display and scope values into _one_ object.

Comment: if i change 'page' to 'popup', it works just fine...still, i did what u recommended but it throws the same error